# BLE: How to get correct service UUID and characteristic UUID?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am a new in Bluetooth connection and I want to add second device in my iOS project. I already have one device, and the new device is very similar with first one, but little bit deferent. I have one process for the two devices, and I did not change a lot of code, just created all value for the new device. My all devices have different name and identifier, first device is working fine.

For creating UUID values, I used UUID generator (https://www.guidgenerator.com/online-guid-generator.aspx).

```
class BleConstants: NSObject {
let deviceTwoServiceUUID = “59DE3994-6A63-4654-8FF0-F85C5163B2F5”
let deviceTwoFirstCharacteristicUUID = “59DE3994-6A63-4654-8FF0-F85C5163B2F6”
let deviceTwoSecondCharacteristicUUID = “59DE3994-6A63-4654-8FF0-F85C5163B2F7”
let deviceOneServiceUUID = “A6AF4483-E210-457B-B9D6-B8A621513D1D”
let deviceOneFirstCharacteristicUUID = “A6AF4483-E210-457B-B9D6-B8A621513D2D”
let deviceOneSecondCharacteristicUUID = “A6AF4483-E210-457B-B9D6-B8A621513D2D”
}

class BleManager: NSObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {
@objc private(set) static var sharedInstance = BleManager()
var cbManager : CBCentralManager? = nil
var currentPeripheral : CBPeripheral? = nil
var secondService : CBService? = nil
var firstService : CBService? = nil
var secondFirstCharacteristic : CBCharacteristic!
var secondSecondCharacteristic : CBCharacteristic!
var firstFirstCharacteristic : CBCharacteristic!
var firstSecondCharacteristic : CBCharacteristic!

func initCentralManager() {
    if cbManager == nil {
        cbManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: [CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey : “MyApp”, CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey: true])            
    }

func deinitCentralManager() {
    cbManager = nil
}

func isBluetoothAvailable() -> Bool {
    return cbManager?.state == CBManagerState.poweredOn
}

func scan() {
    if (cbManager != nil && (cbManager?.isScanning)!) {
        return
    }
    
    discoveredPeripherals.removeAll()
    
    let serviceUUIDs = [CBUUID(string: BleConstants.deviceTwoServiceUUID), CBUUID(string: BleConstants.deviceOneServiceUUID)]
    
    cbManager?.scanForPeripherals(withServices: serviceUUIDs,
                                  options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : 1])
}

func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
    if(!discoveredPeripherals.contains(peripheral)) {
        discoveredPeripherals.append(peripheral)
    }
}

func stopScan() {
    if cbManager != nil && (cbManager?.isScanning)! {
        cbManager?.stopScan()
    }
}

func connect(peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
    if cbManager?.state == CBManagerState.poweredOn {
        if currentPeripheral == nil || currentPeripheral?.state != CBPeripheralState.connected {
            cbManager?.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
        } else {
            cbManager?.cancelPeripheralConnection(peripheral)
        }
    }
}

func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
Device.savePeripheralString(peripheral: peripheral.identifier.uuidString)
    AutoConnect.stop()
DeviceUpdate.updateProgress = .None
Device.isDongleConnected = true
currentPeripheral = peripheral
currentPeripheral?.delegate = self
currentPeripheral?.discoverServices(nil)
disableSleep()
}

func disableSleep() {
    UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true
}

func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
 if error != nil {
        return
    }

    if let services = peripheral.services {

        for service in services {
            if service.uuid.uuidString == BleConstants.deviceTwoServiceUUID {
        Device.dongleType = port.second
                    secondService = service
                peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
        }
            if service.uuid.uuidString == BleConstants.deviceOneServiceUUID {
        Device.dongleType = port.first
                firstService = service
                peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
            } else {
                Log.bt("didDiscoverServices for peripheral not found \(peripheral.identifier.uuidString)")
            }
        }
    }
}

func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {

    for characteristic in service.characteristics! {
        if characteristic.uuid.uuidString == BleConstants.deviceOneFirstCharacteristicUUID {
     firstCharacteristic = characteristic
        }  
    else if characteristic.uuid.uuidString == BleConstants.deviceOneSecondCharacteristicUUID {
           firstSecondCharacteristic = characteristic
        else if characteristic.uuid.uuidString == BleConstants.deviceTwoFirstCharacteristicUUID {
            secondFirstCharacteristic = characteristic
        } else if characteristic.uuid.uuidString == BleConstants.deviceTwoSecondCharacteristicUUID {
    secondSecondCharacteristic = characteristic
        } else {
            Log.bt("didDiscoverCharacteristics not found \(characteristic.uuid.uuidString)")
        }
    }
    
    if Device.dongleType == .deviceTwo {
         openPortDeviceTwo()
    } else {
        openPortDeviceOne()
    }
}
```

}

Data from logs:

For first device:

1. isBluetoothAvailable()
2. scan()
3. CentralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) (peripheral <CBPeripheral: 0x267hg5670, identifier = 98HG761CE-56C3-K767-26HJ-E51BA678Gh56, name = DeviceOne, state = disconnected)
4. CentralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber)
5. scan()
6. CentralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) (peripheral <CBPeripheral: 0x267hg5670, identifier = FJ1478HJ-EH8J-6709-1FH0-1456HGJ0BC901, name = SecondDevice, state = disconnected>)
7. stopScan()
8. connect(peripheral: CBPeripheral) (currentPeripheral nil, currentPeripheral nil)
9. CentralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral
10. centralManager(_:didConnect:) - didConnectPeripheral FJ1478HJ-EH8J-6709-1FH0-1456HGJ0BC901 Second device
11. savedPeripheralString FJ1478HJ-EH8J-6709-1FH0-1456HGJ0BC901 Second device
12. Bluetooth stop()  currentPeripheral Optional(<CBPeripheral: 0x2jk875fe0, identifier = FJ1478HJ-EH8J-6709-1FH0-1456HGJ0BC901, name = SecondDevice, state = connected>)
13. disableSleep()
14. peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?)
15. peripheral(_:didDiscoverServices:) - didDiscoverServices for peripheral FJ1478HJ-EH8J-6709-1FH0-1456HGJ0BC901
16. peripheral(_:didDiscoverServices:) - didDiscoverServices for peripheral.services Optional([<CBService: 0x2jkki2dc0, isPrimary = YES, UUID = 59DE3994-6A63-4654-8FF0-F85C5163B2F5>, <CBService: 0xhj67c240, isPrimary = YES, UUID = Device Information>])
    [<CBService: 0x5678f2dc0, isPrimary = YES, UUID = 59DE3994-6A63-4654-8FF0-F85C5163B2F5>, <CBService: 0x28186c240, isPrimary = YES, UUID = Device Information>], peripheral.services is Optional([<CBService: 0xhjy62dc0, isPrimary = YES, UUID = 59DE3994-6A63-4654-8FF0-F85C5163B2F5>, <CBService: 0x2hju7240, isPrimary = YES, UUID = Device Information>]))
    service.uuid.uuidString  is 59DE3994-6A63-4654-8FF0-F85C5163B2F5 and services is [<CBService: 0xhj7892dc0, isPrimary = YES, UUID = 59DE3994-6A63-4654-8FF0-F85C5163B2F5>, <CBService: 0xhjk678340, isPrimary = YES, UUID = Device Information>]
17. peripheral(_:didDiscoverServices:) - didDiscoverServices SecondDevice 59DE3994-6A63-4654-8FF0-F85C5163B2F5
18. peripheral(_:didDiscoverServices:) - didDiscoverServices for peripheral not found FJ1478HJ-EH8J-6709-1FH0-1456HGJ0BC901

For second device:

1. isBluetoothAvailable()
2. scan()
3. CentralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) (peripheral <CBPeripheral: 0xh6789a40, identifier = 98HG761CE-56C3-K767-26HJ-E51BA678Gh56, name = DeviceOne, state = disconnected)
4. scan()
5. CentralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) (peripheral <CBPeripheral: 0x678jhs0, identifier = H56KIL35-7835-7JKL-2B11-HJKLIYTAA400, name = ThirdDevice, state = disconnected)
6. CentralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber)
7. stopScan()
8. connect(peripheral: CBPeripheral) currentPeripheral nil, currentPeripheral nil
9. CentralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral
10. centralManager(_:didConnect:) - didConnectPeripheral H56KIL35-7835-7JKL-2B11-HJKLIYTAA400
11. savedPeripheralString H56KIL35-7835-7JKL-2B11-HJKLIYTAA400
12. Bluetooth  stop() - currentPeripheral Optional(<CBPeripheral: 0x78jkl680, identifier = H56KIL35-7835-7JKL-2B11-HJKLIYTAA400, name = ThirdDevice, state = connected>)
13. disableSleep()
14. peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?)
15. peripheral(_:didDiscoverServices:) - didDiscoverServices for peripheral H56KIL35-7835-7JKL-2B11-HJKLIYTAA400
16. **peripheral(_:didDiscoverServices:) - didDiscoverServices for peripheral.services Optional([<CBService: 0xlki8901c0, isPrimary = YES, UUID = 59DE3994-6A63-4654-8FF0-F85C5163B2F5 - same like for secondDevice>, <CBService: 0x281111180, isPrimary = YES, UUID = Device Information>])
    services is [<CBService: 0x2827444c0, isPrimary = YES, UUID = 59DE3994-6A63-4654-8FF0-F85C5163B2F5 - same like for secondDevice>, <CBService: 0x282744580, isPrimary = YES, UUID = Device Information>], peripheral.services is Optional([<CBService: 0xlki8901c0, isPrimary = YES, UUID = 59DE3994-6A63-4654-8FF0-F85C5163B2F5 - same like for secondDevice>, <CBService: 0x281111180, isPrimary = YES, UUID = Device Information>]))
    service.uuid.uuidString  is 59DE3994-6A63-4654-8FF0-F85C5163B2F5 - same like for secondDeviceand services is [<CBService: 0x27893kdc0, isPrimary = YES, UUID = 59DE3994-6A63-4654-8FF0-F85C5163B2F5 - same like for secondDevice>, <CBService: 0x679kh8580, isPrimary = YES, UUID = Device Information>]
17. peripheral(_:didDiscoverServices:) - didDiscoverServices ThirdDevice 59DE3994-6A63-4654-8FF0-F85C5163B2F5 - same like for secondDevice
18. peripheral(_:didDiscoverServices:) - didDiscoverServices for peripheral not found H56KIL35-7835-7JKL-2B11-HJKLIYTAA400**

Based on logs information for second device in 16th step app connected to my first service UUID and first characteristic UUID, that is wrong!

Do you have idea,  Did I create UUIDs correct?

P.S:
Android app works fine with both devices.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hat you are doing at step 4 isn't clear; you don't calk `didDiscoverServices`, the delegate method is called after you ask to discover services. Can you [edit] your question to show relevant code and explain your problem more clearly?

Comment: Hi Paulw11, I updated my question and all data, I hope this is better now. Also I added logs data and same print statement information. Do you have any idea? Thanks for your help

Comment: Sorry, this is still not really clear.  Can you explain your problem in one or two sentences.

Comment: Paulw11, I added a new device in my iOS app, and I created service  UUID and characteristic UUID for the new device. When I try to connect to the device, device doesn't recognize his service UUID and characteristic UUID and cannot connect. Instead he tries to use service UUID and characteristic UUID, I set for another device. Is it more clear? Thanks!

Comment: Paulw11, I have let deviceTwoServiceUUID = “59DE3994-6A63-4654-8FF0-F85C5163B2F5” and let deviceOneServiceUUID = “A6AF4483-E210-457B-B9D6-B8A621513D1D”. First device uses deviceOneServiceUUID for his connection and it works fine. Second device uses deviceOneServiceUUID too, but must use deviceTwoServiceUUID. And I don't understand why, in my code I set up it on deviceTwoServiceUUID.

Comment: This - " Second device uses deviceOneServiceUUID too, but must use deviceTwoServiceUUID" isn't clear. Do you mean you are discovering the second device and it is reporting that it has the first device's service UUID?

Comment: Paulw11, right.

Comment: Are the two devices the same physical device?  Are they an iOS device advertising a peripheral or some other kind of hardware?  I note that you have multiple peripherals but only a single `currentPeripheral` property - You should probably use the passed `peripheral` in `didConnect` rather than `currentPeripheral`.

Comment: Please power on both devices and scan them using nRF Connect or another BLE-Scanner. A Service UUID is not unique for one device, but for one service. If the second device offers the same service the service UUID is also the same.

Comment: Paulw11, these are two different physical device. This is not iOS device, these devices collection data and it created in a different language and I collect this data from these devices through the iOS application. I will try use your idea, thanks! Probable could be something else, because I have more then two devices, and I can connect and collect data from all of them, it means that the didConnect works fine. I see two reasons: I created Service UUID not correct for the second device, hardware for the two devices very similar and probable this creates the issue

Comment: M. Kotzjan, Thanks for your recommendation. I used this nRF Connect, and scanned the both devices, both have same service UUID and Characteristic UUID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Receiving the same service and characteristic UUID for multiple BLE devices is perfectly normal and only means that all the devices offer exactly the same service.

*For example*:
If you have two devices which measure the heart rate of a person, e.g. a smartwatch, both devices might offer the heart rate service with the same UUID.

If you want to differentiate between the device you can use the **identifier** which you received in step 3 of your provided log.

Comment: M. Kotzjan, thanks a lot for the informations, this is good to know! I used peripheral.name to differentiate between the device and I can continue the process.